# Angular: convert timestamps to specific timezone, respecting daylight saving time

Tags: angular, time, timezone, dst

In my Angular application, I need to display timestamps (given as Unix epoch milliseconds) in Eastern European time. The following is almost correct, but ignores daylight savings time:

```
{{ timestamp | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss':'UTC+2' }}
```

I tried replacing `UTC+2` with `EET`, but this just results in all times being converted to the user's local timezone (like when the parameter is omitted). The timestamps can be from any date, so it should consider whether DST was in effect at that time, not just when the code is being run. DST in Europe lasts from the last Sunday of March to the last Sunday of October.

Comment: Is `timestamp`always UTC ?

Comment: Yes, it's Unix time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

This function will give you the information if a given date is inside the CEST (Central Europe Summer Time) period:

```
lastSunday(year, month) {
    var date = new Date(year, month, 1, 12);
    let weekday = date.getDay();
    let dayDiff = weekday===0 ? 7 : weekday;
    let lastSunday = date.setDate(date.getDate() - dayDiff);
    return date;
}

isCEST(d: Date): boolean {
  let year = d.getFullYear();
    
  let startCET: Date = this.lastSunday(year, 3);
  let endCET: Date = this.lastSunday(year, 10);

  return !(startCET < d && d < endCET);
}

offset(d: Date): string {
  return isCEST(d) ? 'UTC+2' : 'UTC+1'
}
```

Now you can change your pipe to this:

```
{{ timestamp | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss': offset(timestamp) }}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems you forgot to include the lastSunday function though.

Comment: @laurt Sorry about that. Just included it...